# Error: expected <block end>, but found Scalar

Tags: yaml, minecraft

I was doing a YAML file but an error occurred:

```
ERROR:

while parsing a block mapping
  in "<unicode string>", line 10, column 3:
      name:
      ^
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
  in "<unicode string>", line 54, column 7:
        -'cEscolhaUmServer'
          ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is not the same as [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html).

Comment: error is somehow related to line 54, please share all the YAML or at least lines up to line 54

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to insert a space between the item indicator (`-`) and the item (`'cEscolhaUmServer'). You should try:

```
- 'cEscolhaUmServer'
```

Please note that the quotes around `cEscolhaUmServer` are superfluous.

Comment: ```in 'string', line 10, column 3:

name:

^

expected <block end>, but found Scalar

in 'string', line 54, column 8:

- 'cEscolhaUmServer'

^
```

Comment: It is time you showed all of your YAML, or at least everything up to line 54